# python package structure for importing when distributing AND local, non-built development/usage

Tags: python, package

I've created a very simple use case that models my larger efforts and is described below.  I have a package (foo).  I intend to perform local development/testing with the package (ie. run bin/cli_script.py, or ipython/import foo).  I do this by managing my environment and setting PYTHONPATH.  Once happy, I intend to build a wheels, then pip install it for deployment testing (I do this in a completely different venv though I don't have to).  If i make my import statements work for local development, it breaks using imports in the package and vice versa. Never can get both approaches working together.

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── bin
│   └── cli_script.py
├── build
├── contributing.md
├── dist
├── foo
│   ├── a_model.py
│   ├── b_model.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── example_module.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup_environment.sh
├── setup.py
└── tests
```

Within the package, foo subdir is my library folder which is intended to be used with normal python parlance (from foo import a_model, or import foo, etc).  There is a bin/cli_script.py driver that imports and uses the package library also.  This script is intended to be installed in a virtualenv and made available on path in a venv environment.

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

# Add our unit testing area
#import sys
#sys.path.append('./tests')

setuptools.setup(
    name="foo",                               # Replace with your package name
    version="0.0.1",                               # see pep 440
    author="foobar",
    author_email="blah@email.com",
    maintainer="***",
    maintainer_email="***",
    description="Test",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://www.google.com",  # github pages
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.0',
    install_requires=[],                           # list 3rd party packages/versions
    #test_suite="tests",                           # folder for unit/functional tests
    setup_requires=['wheel'],
    scripts=['bin/cli_script.py'],                 # callable script to register (updates PATH)
)
```

Contents of common.py:

```
class CommonModel:
    """ common to all device """

    def __init__(self):
        self.subtype = 'common'
        self.status = ""
        self.serial = ""

    def show(self):
        print("\tsubtype: %s" % self.subtype)
        print("\tstatus: %s" % self.status)
        print("\tserial: %s" % self.serial)
```

Contents of a_model.py:

```
import common

class A_Model(common.CommonModel):
    """ Model A """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.subtype = 'a_model'
        self.a_new_param = 'blah'
```

contents of b_model:

```
import common

class B_Model(common.CommonModel):
    """ Model B """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.subtype = 'b_model'
```

I feel like the answer is going to be how I construct my **init**.py file, right now its empty.  Any help greatly appreciated and happy to include additional captures of the actual error (didn't want to bloat this too much initially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, i accidentally broke something I *thought* was consistent (for something else).  Basically it was my PYTHONPATH - it was pointing to the package subfolder containing the library/modules (In my description it was shown below and fixed by setting it to the package folder.  ie:

```
$ tree foo
foo                 **<----PYTHONPATH (fixed)**

├── bin
│   └── cli_script.py
├── build
├── contributing.md
├── dist
├── foo              **<----PYTHONPATH (Broken)**
│   ├── a_model.py
│   ├── b_model.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── example_module.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup_environment.sh
├── setup.py
└── tests
```